# How to integrate google pay & apple pay as payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Magento ver. 2.4.0

How to integrate google pay & apple pay as payment method ?

Comment: I have the same question as the topic owner. up up

Comment: I think Braintree provides solution for both

Comment: seprate gpay extension https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/google-pay-plugin-for-magento-2.html

Comment: and there are couple of paid apple pay extensions are avalible I cannot share here as they are not open source but you can easily get

Comment: Braintree provides but not for the magento version I am using.

I think stripe is the option.